# Getting error when trying to use hasNext in Java

Tags: java, arrays, count, filereader, filewriter

I have a particular set of code, which is going to read a text from a file (Alice.txt) and then put every word into an array and count the total amount of words and the words individually.

I have a draft of something, but blocking my way towards my goal is an error which I get. First, the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Oblig3A{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    OrdAnalyse O = new OrdAnalyse();
    OrdAnalyse.analyseMet();
    }
}

class OrdAnalyse {
    public static void analyseMet() {
    Scanner Inn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Vennligst oppgi navn til lagringsfilen: ");
    String Filen;
    Filen = Inn.nextLine();

    try {
        File skrivFil = new File(Filen);
        FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(skrivFil);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        File lesFil = new File ("Alice.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(lesFil);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int teller=0;
        int i=0;
        while(lesFil.hasNext()){
        teller++;
        lesFil.next();
        }
        String[] ordArray = new String[teller];
        int[] antall = new int[teller]
        do{
        ordArray[i]=lesFil.next();
        }
        while(lesFil.hasNext());
        System.out.println(ordArray.length);

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Oblig3A.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        while(lesFil.hasNext()){
                    ^
  symbol:   method hasNext()
  location: variable lesFil of type File
```

Is there anyone who could give me a pointer as to why this is happening? I really don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasNext()` is a method in the [`Scanner` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), which parses a stream into tokens.
It doesn't exist in a `File`.

You want to create a `new Scanner(lesFil)` and use that instead.

You also don't need your two readers.

Comment: Got any idea as to why I now get an NoSuchElementException? I remade the code so that it just makes a file named: Opplysning.txt instead of using scanner and input variable Filen, and then made the changes you recommended, and even ensured that there is indeed a Alice.txt and a Opplysning.txt in the same folder as the program. But to no avail. When I removed the try-catch-loop it said it needed a declared exception at the first filewriter-line, is it the problem?

Comment: Okay, so I understand that it is probably one of the next-operators, then? I'll try and see what I can find.
Might it be because I got two loops that read the entire file to the end? So that it is read to the end after the first loop, and when the second loop starts, it doesn't find any elements, throwing the exception?

Answer (score 2):

The `File` class doesn't have a `hasNext()` method.  Perhaps you wanted to create a `Scanner` using the `File`.  The [`Scanner` class has a `hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) method.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lesFil);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `readLine()` on `br`, not `hasNext()` on `lesFil`. Files aren't iterators; doing line-by-line reading is why you created the `BufferedReader`. If you want a `hasNext()`, create a `Scanner` like others have said.

Answer (score 0):

Your while isn't supposed to end with a ;